# How to define pydantic model for choice of keys

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

```
{
      "type": "thirdparty",
      "details": {
        "key": "postgres",
        "host": "test",
        "id": "88c8fo90"
      }
}
```

or

```
{
      "type": "weburl",
      "details": {
        "url": "https://www.google.com",
      }
}
```

here my details keys are changing as per the type. How can I achieve this in pydantic? And these json is inside a couple of nested models.

Comment: as far as I am aware a way to model this is to have a `Details` model with `key`, `host`, `id` and `url` all as `Optional[str] = None`, and add validators that use `type` and validates with the body of `Details`, maybe others will have better suggestions